# Fixed return of invested money in manufacturing plant

Tags: halal-haram, money

Assalam,
I had invested money in oil manufacturing plant where the owner gives me fixed return on invested money. The agreement is working since three years. Is it halal to accept that income according to Islamic view?

Comment: of course you'd better to do more research about thAT. But as I mentioned, I think it could be considered as Riba if you solely obtain interest in any case.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, giving an amount of money to someone or even companies or other job by the intention of obtaining solely interest would not be Halal. because perhaps we can term it as Riba (interest). Since you pay a specific amount of money that you constantly obtain interest, not disadvantage. So it could be considered as Riba. Then as far as I know, you should write a contract that you be partner in both interest and disadvantage, not solely in the interest.

Answer (score 0):

Your profits must be associated with the performance of the business you've invested in. Otherwise if you've used the money to obtain the right to even more money then that is interest.

Comment: Hi. Please go through the **Avoid overt self-promotion.** section of this site's [help/behavior].

Comment: This is not self-promotion this is a tool to help Muslims understand their economics. I will not forgive you on the day of judgement , and I hope the users don't either, for your depriving them of a good source of knowledge.

Comment: I also guess, you're on the blacklist now, every time your rep is getting cleaned, plz maintain some quality while answering don't just answer for the sake of answering, although your intents are good. :)

Comment: moreover, your answering to very old financial questions, just a little reminder, they might have got their solutions by now or their problem might have been solved, so also consider that while answering, but I'm not discouraging u by any means.